# Notification intent is not launched in corner cases

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

Here's my scenario:

1. I show a notification that is not clearable ([`FLAG_NO_CLEAR`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_NO_CLEAR)),
2. I set a pending intent that launches an `Activity`,
3. In the launched `Activity`, the user presses something and I launch another `Activity`,
4. Clicking on the notification again **does not start/show the `Activity` in the pending intent**, which is very annoying. I would like the initial `Activity` to be either re-launched or brought to the front. However, I can't seem to be able to achieve this.

Relevant code for notification:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, RemindersActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // the docs say this is required
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
n.setLatestEventInfo(this, getString(R.string.app_name), text, pi);
```

After that, it's just normal `startActivity()` (at step 3). Here's what I get in logcat:

```
I/ActivityManager(  147): Starting activity: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=my.package/my.package.RemindersActivity bnds=[0,387][480,483] }
W/InputManagerService(  147): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@45a33fc8
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? The only one that comes to my mind is to use a broadcast intent instead of an activity intent (and launch the activity from the receiver), but I'm not even sure that would work.

Comment: Have you tried tweaking the attributes of your root activity? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I can't seem to be able to achieve this.

Try adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, or the combination of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, to the `Intent`.

Comment: I have tried both your suggestions plus **mibollma**'s suggestion (`clearTaskOnLaunch="true"`), nothing worked.

Comment: Hmm, actually `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` seems to work now, I have no idea what I did earlier that it didn't. Thanks.